# Angular JS Forms submit not sending model data

Tags: angularjs

In the following example, `message` is undefined when I display it in the controller after the event is fired.  Why?

```
<form>
  <input type="text" ng-model="message.Title" />
  <textarea ng-model="message.Content"></textarea>         
  <input type="submit" value="Send Message" ng-click="sendMessage(message)" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.sendMessage = function(message) {
  console.log(message);
}
```

My code seems identical to the documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) except my controller manages the entire "page" not just the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow nevermind, apparently when you submit with blank values it doesn't even create the object.

Answer (score 4):

I see you've found your problem, but I'd like to propose a solution to prevent your problem anyway:

```
<form name="messageForm" ng-submit="sendMessage(message)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="message.Title" required/>
  <span ng-show="messageForm.title.$error.required && messageForm.title.$dirty">required</span><br/>
  <textarea ng-model="message.Content"></textarea>         
  <input type="submit" value="Send Message" ng-disabled="messageForm.$invalid" />
</form>
```

The above will make the Title required, display an error message, and disable your submit button if the form isn't valid.